# ace-editor get text between braces

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

How can ace-editor get the value of code which is between braces like:

```
 {
        "name":"Product",
        "properties":
        {
                "id":
                {
                        "type":"number",
                        "description":"Product identifier",
                        "required":true
                },
                "name":
                {
                        "description":"Name of the product",
                        "type":"string",
                        "required":true
                }
        }
}
```

if cursor is on: `"type":"number"`

Then it should return

```
                {
                        "type":"number",
                        "description":"Product identifier",
                        "required":true
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code in [jumpToMatching](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/editor.js#L1748) which finds next `{}` and then calls findMatchingBracket, once you have the range call `editor.session.getTextRange(range)`

Comment: This is not perfect but giving text between braces: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nomzz/LFapm/2/)

I'm getting text range but it is not showing braces in some cases

Comment: it depends on which bracket you find the first opening or closing see http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/55/edit

Comment: try to click name or id, it stil misses the last bracket

Comment: yes works perfect sweet, can you please elaborate logic of points little bit?

Comment: there is one problem when it goes deep, it only selects deeper one, even in outer scope. http://jsfiddle.net/LFapm/4/

Comment: just call findnext several times to find parent http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/73/edit
Btw. why do you use jsfiddle it's quite broken? jsbin is somewhat nicer, but i wish it used ace instead of codemirror (or at least disabled intrusive autoindent).

Comment: Thanks, no reasons to use jsfiddle over jsbin, its just had been using for a while, will use now jsbin :), BTW any reason you prefer ace over codemirror, i see adobe's bracket also using codemirror and many others, just curious to know comparison matrix

Comment: AFAIK Brackets used codemirror because of license https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/1242.

Ace have multiselect support, and better default configuration: fold widgets, nicer word highlight, findbar, brace autopairing etc.. With codemirror everyone recreates this things, with different quality. The most frustrating thing about codemirror on jsbin is too aggressive autoindent.